# Dependent drop-down list for two columns in the same table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, dropdown

Basically what I am trying to do is have two drop-down lists that are depended of each other show a drop down for either the first names or last names available of a person when the other is selected.
To clarify. I have a big list of client information in a table. One row includes first names and one row includes last names. What I am looking for is when I fill out a userform and select either a first name or last name in one of the boxes, for all possible first or last names to appear in the other drop-down list.
So if I select "Mike" in my first list, all the last names for people named Mike will appear in a list.

It can either be a formula or vba code, whichever is best.

Comment: You've posted your requirement. Now, please edit your question and post the code that you have written, so we can help you with that. Please read: [ask]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how the data is displayed?  I have had one drop down based on a range of data, a second drop down looks at that dropdown using indirect function and then brings through the corresponding table.  However, that required a table, which you could create a dynamic one.